# How to sum depths of a binary tree, why is my code failing tests?- not sure how to set up binary trees in my IDE so can't use debugger

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am solving a question where we are asked to `return the sum of the Depths` of all the nodes in a `Binary Tree`.

For example:
[image]

Usually I would use a `debugger` to find the error in my code, but I don't know how to set up `trees/binary tree in my IDE`.

My code below passes most of the tests, but fails some. It fails the above test, and produces an `output of 20` instead of `16`.

```
def nodeDepths(root):
    queue = [root]
    sumOfDepths = 0
    currentDepth = 0
    while len(queue):
        for _ in range(len(queue)):
            currentNode = queue.pop()
            sumOfDepths += currentDepth
            if currentNode.left:
                queue.append(currentNode.left)
            if currentNode.right:
                queue.append(currentNode.right)
        currentDepth += 1

    return sumOfDepths
```

Any suggestions where the code fails/is doing something unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the source of your error is in your `current_node = queue.pop()` statement.  According to the docs *"The argument passed to the method is optional. If not passed, the default index -1 is passed as an argument (index of the last item)."*  Because you are pulling the last entry from the queue everything works okay until you have entries in the queue from different depths.  To fix this problem use `current_node = queue.pop(0)`, this will always pull the oldest entry from the queue.

Comment: Quick question too, if we do pop(0), am I right in assuming that this is an O(n) operation on its own? Since we need to shift all items in the list one step left?

Comment: Yes it is a O(n) operation because python simply moves the pointer to the start of the list to the next position, it doesn't shift anything.